# Summing randomly generated values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, random

I am trying to randomly select values from a short list, sum them, then iterate that process many times. So far I think I am successful in generating the values:

```html
Work so far

    0.4855981 0 0 FALSE
 Price   0.337666609 0 0 FALSE
1 $29.74    0.808816075 0 0 FALSE
2 $0.85    0.906751484 0 0 FALSE
3 $38.24    0.10572928 1 4 17
4 $17    0.957321497 0 0 FALSE
5 $25.50    0.644195743 0 0 FALSE
6 $18.70    0.133302328 0 0 FALSE
7 $29.75    0.907771163 0 0 FALSE
8 $14.45    0.156311546 0 0 FALSE
9 $30.60    0.871958447 0 0 FALSE
10 $26.34    0.0790938 1 14 24.65
11 $11.05    0.696383544 0 0 FALSE
12 $124.95   0.080728462 1 3 38.24
13 $9.35    0.03717127 1 10 26.34
14 $24.65    0.970430159 0 0 FALSE
15 $41.65    0.814402286 0 0 FALSE
    0.462967917 0 0 FALSE
    0.646432058 0 0 FALSE
    0.49384003 0 0 FALSE
    0.381349746 0 0 FALSE
    0.129594937 0 0 FALSE
    0.576582174 0 0 FALSE
    0.37483142 0 0 FALSE
       
      Total 106.23
```

In any set there are 24 attempts at selecting an item from the price list. What I have done is randomly generate a number and if it less than 0.125 (1/8 chance of getting a value from the price list per attempt) then I generate a random number between 1 and 15 and then vlookup to get the price.

However I want to iterate this process many times, so say out of 100 times each consisting of 24 attempts, what is the average value I return. I cannot find a way to simply add the number to itself each time I update the random numbers, and my VBA is pretty limited - I was considering a loop that has a clickbutton to refresh the numbers. Pseudo code since I know very little VBA:

```html
for 1=1:100
  clickbutton() #to refresh
  grandtotal=grandtotal+total
end

averagevalue=grandtotal/i
```

I know it seems really easy, but I have not had luck searching how refresh with the clickbutton, or if that is even the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code is a good place to start! If you name the total cell in your sheet to "Total", you should be able to run the below, which is my take on your pseudo code:

```
noRuns = 100
grandTotal = 0
For i = 1 to noRuns
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    grandTotal = grandTotal + Range("Total").Value
Next i
MsgBox "The average value is " & grandTotal / noRuns
```

If that doesn't work, have a play with it and let me know how you get on.